Applying the law of total variance
Say we have a sample of 100 normally distributed payments, with mean=1000 dollars and standard deviation= 100 dollars. 10% of these payments were made in error and should be refunded their full payment amount. The other 90% will have a refund amount of 0 dollars. What is the variance of the refunded amount?
I am trying to solve this problem using the law of total variance. X is a binary outcome with probability of payment error=10%.
The law of total variance states:
Var(Y)= E[Var(Y|X)] + Var(E[Y|X])
I think I understand that the first term is just the average of the variance of Y over each condition of X. So when X=payment error, the variance is 100^2, or 10,000. When x=no payment error, the refund amount is always 0 so the variance is 0. The weighted average is (10,000 x 0.1) + (0 x .9) or 1,000.
So E[Var(Y|X)]= 1000.
However I am very confused by what the second term means. I believe the expected value of Y given X would be 0.1X. But I don't understand how to get the variance of this term or what it really represents. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

The first term is the variance caused by $Y$ varying, the second term is the variance caused by $X$ varying.
To calculate the second term, find the expectation of $Y$ for each value of $X$, and then take its variance over the distribution of $X$.
If $X=1$ then $\text{E}[Y]=1000$.  If $X=0$ then $\text{E}[Y]=0$.
So $\text{Var}(\text{E}\left[Y\mid X\right])$ is $1000^2$ times $\text{Var}(X)$.
Since $X$ is binomial with $\Pr(X=1)=0.1$, $\text{Var}(X)=0.1\times0.9=0.09$
So $\text{E}[\text{Var}(Y\mid X)]=90000$
This gives you a total variance of
$1000+90000=91000$
and so a standard deviation of about 300.
